# Excel 2007. Date and time formulas searching

Tags: excel

i have a cell named a1 in excel sheet containing the Date and time in one cell. i want to extract the date and time separately in cell a2 and a3 after that i want to separate the time values in AM and Pm on two other cells named a4 and a4. its my challenge no one can easily solve my problem. Note my answer will be solve only with the Office 2007.

Comment: Just make all the cells equal to A1, then format then as needed in cell formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try =DateValue() and =TimeValue() for getting the date portion and the time portion. Use =If(TimeValue()>=.5,,) for PM and =If(TimeValue()<.5,,) for AM.